# What is the best Auth bundle for Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, permissions, roles

there are a lot of `Auth bundles` in Laravel, but I really get in stuck on which one is better for a purpose like :

I want to create a web-site with `simple users`, `superadmin`, `admin`, `content-manager`, `translater`.
The site will be a blog-like, with articles, a lot of pages, posts, comments and so on. 
I want also to have ability in `superadmin` panel to be able to give permissions to each role, and in ideal case, to give specific permissions *`routes`* for specific users of the same role.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[laratrust](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust) without question is the best one, great documentation and suggested by Taylor Otwell himself